# Why does clear Python virtualenv use system Python library?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pytest

I am newbie in Automation (Python + Pytest).
I try to use clear virtualenv on my mac, but somehow Pytest runs from a local directory.

So, what I try to do:

1. I have a project with many pip packages (pytest, selene etc.).
2. I do :

```
$ pip3 install --user virtualenv
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
$ cd venv/
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ echo $PATH
> /Users/.../venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
$ which python
> /Users/.../venv/bin/python
$ which pytest
> /usr/local/bin/pytest
```

And when I try to run my pytest - it does! But shouldn't!
If I delete Pytest from my mac as:

```
$ pip3 uninstall pytest
```

it works, and I got clear venv.

---

**Python 3.7.4**

**This is pytest version 5.2.1**, imported from `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest.py`

setuptools registered plugins: pytest-reportportal-1.0.4 at `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_reportportal/plugin.py`

Can someone say what I do wrong? Or what is the problem with it?
How to create clear venv without dependencies from local PATH libs?

Comment: `cd venv/; source venv/bin/activate`…? That seems wrong…

Comment: And, well, your `$PATH` includes `/usr/local/bin`, in which `pytest` is. Executables in `.../venv/bin` are simply prioritised higher, but it would be highly inconvenient to be looking at *only* `.../venv/bin` and ignore the system `bin` directories, since that affects *all* commands, not just the ones involving Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior seems perfectly normal, working as intended.

Install *pytest* in your virtual environment, it will then take priority over the one globally installed, since it will be located *higher up* in your `$PATH`. Consider uninstalling the global one if you don't intend to use it.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. Looks like it work in such way.